# 'Developer' role unable to add devices or edit provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I have been assigned a 'developer' role in the team. I was able to add devices/provisioning profiles, until today when I signed in and now everything is greyed out. I looked of any news if the 'User and Roles' have been changed by Apple but couldn't find any help.

Screenshots (unable to uploaded images here):

[First](https://ibb.co/D9TXfqt)

[Second](https://ibb.co/C5ykbFz)

As seen in Screenshot 2, I am not allowed to edit that provisioning profile, which I am pretty sure I have done earlier. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: It has been updated, https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Answer (score 0):

Recently Apple update the roles of Developer portal and App Store Connect. But I'm pretty sure that even before that, Developer role cannot add/edit devices/provisioning profiles directly on Developer portal. Thought, you can always do it by using Xcode (add new devices, create your local provisionning profile). Hope this helps.